# Read a specific string in a txt file and convert the string to an int C

Tags: c, file

I have a txt file that I read each line of it with this function :
the txt file is like this

> NOMLOT:300
>   0001::16:27::47::68:79::3::::43:53::71:81::17:28:31::59:::85
>   0002:15::32::8::74:79::3::::43:53::71:81::17:28:31::59:::85

my get_line function is here

```
char *get_line(char *buf, int n, FILE *f, int line)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0 ;i<line;i++)
    {
        if(fgets(buf,n,f) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1 ] = '\0';
    }
    return buf;
}
```

For example if I want to print the first line it will look like :

```
char input[60];
get_line(input,TAILLE,fichier,ligne);
printf("1st line: \n");
for (i=0;i<60;i++)
{
    printf("%c",input[i]);
}
```

What I want to do , is to read only the 300 and convert that 300 into an INT and save it , so with this value I can loop my program to read the all existing line , starting from the 2nd line .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    get_line(input,TAILLE,fichier,ligne);
    printf("1st line: \n");
    for (i=0;i<60 && input[i];i++){
        printf("%c",input[i]);
    }
    int num;
    if(1==sscanf(input, "NOMLOT:%d", &num)){
        printf("\n%d\n", num);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all, a comment. Your `get_line()` function is going to be grossly inefficient if you are reading the file sequentially (e.g. read line 1, then read line 2, then read line 3) because you will have to do O(n^2) line reads to read n lines. You should find a way to structure your program so that you read each line at most one time.

As for the actual problem, are you familiar with the C functions [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)?

Assuming your `input` buffer contains the line you want (regex `"[^:]*:\d+"`, e.g. "NOMLOT:300"), you can do something like this:

```
const char * num_pos = strtok(input, ":"); // get the position of the colon
if (! num_pos)
    ; // colon not found, so handle error
else
    {
    int num = atoi(num_pos + 1); // convert the string starting one char past the colon to an integer
    // do processing now that you have the number...
    }
```

Comment: get_line I use this function cause I need to put each line on an array to display a bingo coupon !

Comment: I tried what you suggested @0xbe5077ed , but when I print the num , it shows me only 0 , or what I want is 300

Comment: That is probably because your buffer doesn't contain what you think it contains. Use a debugger to check the content of `input` before you call `strtok(...)`. If it contains `"NOMLOT:300"` as you expect, then use a debugger to check the value of `num_pos` before you call `atoi(...)`. If `atoi(...)` encounters anything but a valid integer it will return zero.